# Artemis 2.6.0 three node cluster

Tags: activemq-artemis

i want to build a 3 nodes (avoid split brain) symmetric cluster with high availability using replication. In addition I would like to be able to load balanced messages between nodes

how should this be achieved?

- option 1: 1 master with 2 slaves
- option 2: 3 colocated master/slave
  nodes

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 isn't really an option as the slaves will not participate in the voting process which means split-brain will not be mitigated.  The only option you have left (of the 2 you listed, of course) is to use 3 colocated master/slaves.

Comment: 10x a lot for the quick response Justin. 
In case of colocated cluster, could you please try and help me with 
http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Artemis-2-6-0-colocated-HA-not-working-td4744633.html

10x again

Comment: relevant bug was opened: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2165

Comment: @justin-bertram For option 1 in this question, does using Network Pinger  avoid split brain ?

Comment: The network pinger can help to avoid split brain, but it's not a panacea.